I want the background to have a different color below the svg and a different color above svg, I set as a background, How can I achieve that?
I want to have a separate background color below the svg and a separate background color above the svg.
Note that I have set the background Image for the body element and I will be using a grid layout above it with background-color set to transparent.
I have tried using solid linear gradients, as background color, but that would cover the svg image. I want the svg image to be at the top of the background color.

If it's possible to set background-color as linear gradient like this. It would look similar to the result I'm hoping for
body {
  background-color: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    var(--color-background-primary-light) 0%,
    var(--color-background-primary-light) 40%,
    var(--color-background-primary-dark) 40%,
    var(--color-background-primary-dark) 100%
  );
  background-image: url("/images/bg-curvy-desktop.svg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 30%;
}


This is the design I'm trying to recreate.

I fixed it by using the svg in html and using these properties for the svg image.
.curve {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-background-primary-dark);
  mask-image: url(../../images/bg-curvy-desktop.svg);
  mask-size: cover;
}

And then in the section I did position relative
.section-header {
  position: relative;
}

Here is the HTML code
<div class="grid__container">
      <nav class="grid__child grid__child--nav">NAVIGATION</nav>
      <header class="grid__child grid__child--header section-header">
        <img
          class="curve"
          src="./images/bg-curvy-desktop.svg"
          alt="background-image"
        />
      </header>
      <section class="grid__child grid__child--features">FEATURES</section>
      <section class="grid__child grid__child--about">ABOUT</section>
      <section class="grid__child gird__child--reviews">REVIEWS</section>
      <section class="grid__child grid__child--cta">CALL TO ACTION</section>
      <footer class="grid__child grid__child--footer">FOOTER</footer>
    </div>

